# Cross Product Algebras references

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, operator-algebras

Can someone give some references to introductory books or online notes about group algebras and cross-product algebras ?
I've already searched on Google (but only for some online notes). The purpose of this request is just to self-learning, so I'd like something at the level of an introduction, if possible with comprehensive proves of the results.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: As a starting point, perhaps Piotr Soltan's lecture notes might fit the bill? http://www.fuw.edu.pl/~psoltan/prace/C*-algebras,%20group%20actions%20and%20crossed%20products%20(lecture%20notes).pdf

Answer (score 1):

Siegfried Echterhoff has a very nice notes about crossed products of $C^\ast$-algebras which is available at arXiv: [See here.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1006.4975)

Besides that, I recommend the book [Crossed Products of $C^*$-Algebras,](http://www.ams.org/publications/authors/books/postpub/surv-134) by Dana Williams.

Comment: arXiv fronend seems to be down for some time - but the arXiv identifier from the above link is enough to find that text: https://arxiv.org/abs/1006.4975

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a book with a more algebraic flavor and introductory level is the book by Cesar Polcino "an introduction to group rings" or the classic Don Passman book "the algebraic structure of group rings" where the crossed products are studied with some depth.